# Magento 2.3.1 Inventory reservations cleanup not working

Tags: inventory, magento2.3.1, reservations

Even though cron job seems to be working fine, it does not cleanup the inventory_reservation table.

This is the result I get back from the cron.log:

> [2019-06-03 00:00:11] main.INFO: Cron Job
>   inventory_cleanup_reservations is successfully finished. Statistics:
>   {"sum":0.0029830932617188,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":70656,"realmem_start":161742848,"emalloc_start":160341872}
>   [] []

It has no effect on store but I still would like to fix this. What could be the problem?

Comment: What problem is that causing? Are your stock figures incorrect?

Comment: It's not causing any problems but I assume the table must be cleaned, clearing the reservation and shipping entry if they match the same orderID.

Answer (score 0):

Cleanup tool removes just fully compensated reservations, but not the whole reservation table. 
You can read more about that here - https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/wiki/Salable-Quantity-Calculation-and-Mechanism-of-Reservations#reservation-api
Removal of processed Reservations section